# What's the best way to handle a matching donation?

Tags: civicontribute

We often receive annual appeal donations that include a matching gift from the donor's employer.  Is there a better way to handle these other than creating a record for the employer, and soft-crediting the match to the donor?

Answer (score 4):

This is highly dependent on your development department's workflow - but I'd say what you described is the most popular approach.

If you do go this route, you may want to consider installing an extension I wrote called [Auto Matching Gift](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.automatchinggift).  It's mostly a labor-saver: When you enter the original gift, you select the Matching Gift organization from a list.  A pending contribution will be created on their record, and it will be soft-credited to the original donor.

Note that this was developed for an organization that pays for a service of all organizations that match gifts - so if you have to create the organization first, it's not much of a time-saver.  Hopefully one day I (or someone else) will improve it to allow adding organizations on the fly.

Comment: I second that this is probably the popular approach. It is very helpful to have a record of all the employers that are awarding matching gifts while also being able to see what individual is responsible for prompting the gift.